# Expand a compound variable containing two or more variables

Tags: bash, variable

I have these 5 variables:

```
drt="/var/www/html"

drt_chown="chown -R www-data:www-data ${drt}/"
drt_chmod="chmod -R a-x,a=rX,u+w ${drt}/"
rss="systemctl restart nginx.service"
rpf="/etc/init.d/php*-fpm restart"
```

I tried to combine/concatenate/add the last 4 variables, inside a **compound variable** named `rse`, just so it would be comfortable for me to expand all of them at once:

```
rse="${drt_chown} ; ${drt_chmod} ; ${rss} ; ${rpf}"
```

I then tried to expand `rse`:

```
${rse}
```

Sadly, this expansion of `rse` failed with the following set of errors:

```
chown: cannot access ';': No such file or directory
chown: cannot access 'chmod': No such file or directory
chown: cannot access 'a-x,a=rX,u+w': No such file or directory
chown: cannot access ';': No such file or directory
chown: cannot access 'systemctl': No such file or directory
chown: cannot access 'restart': No such file or directory
chown: cannot access 'nginx.service': No such file or directory
chown: cannot access ';': No such file or directory
chown: cannot access 'restart': No such file or directory
```

---

My question is what's the correct, and shortest way to expand my compound variable? Or at least, what's the best alternative in your opinion?

The aspect of **assignment** is quite important for me here.

---

**Notes:**

<sub>1. The current question is a followup for [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/423452/combine-2-or-more-variables-into-one-variable-simple-variable-concatenation), asked by mistake (because I actually meant to ask the current question).</sub>

<sub>2. Keywords for Google (unavailable in tags): Expanding a master variable / mega variable or a variable of variables.</sub>

Comment: I suspect that you should place your commands in string with single ' instead of " - give it a try :)

Comment: When a variable containing a simple command expands in a place where a command is expected, it works, but when you have a compound command (a list of simple ones), you will need to use `eval`. (writing on a phone is hard, so won't answer properly, sorry)

Comment: This, however, looks like a good candidate for a shell function... or at least a (urhg) alias.

Comment: I need that as a variable-compound because I use it in scripts and AFAIK there is no "easy" way to utilize aliases in scripts. Otherwise I would indeed use an alias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concatenating the variables isn't the issue, both assignments to `rse` will concatenate the strings just fine. The issue is the same as with your previous question: special operators like `;` and `&&` (and `&` and `|` and `>` and `"` etc.) aren't interpreted after variable expansion.

That is to say, there's no redirection or conditional here, just variable expansion inside a string (a sort of string concatenation). The quotes within `cmd` aren't special either:

```
$ cmd1='echo "foo" > bar'
$ cmd2='echo "false"'
$ cmd="$cmd1 || $cmd2"
$ $cmd
"foo" > bar || echo "false"
```

---

You should probably use functions instead, e.g.

```
drt="/var/www/html"
drt_chown() { chown -R www-data:www-data "${drt}/"; }
```

and then run it like any command, with just `drt_chown`. Note that it would apply the current value of the variable `drt`.

Better yet, make the function accept a parameter:

```
www_chown() { chown -R www-data:www-data "$1"; }

www_chown /var/www/html
```

Then if you want to, you can make a function that calls the other functions.

```
doitall() {
    drt_chown &&
    drt_chmod &&
    ...
}
```

Comment: Please forgive me, in `special operators like ; and && (and & and | and > etc.) aren't interpreted after variable expansion.` what do you mean by `after`? If I understand correct, the moment one expands a variable, this should be "the end of the line" for any code that deals with these special operators and one must go down one line and expand the second variable there, and so forth. If that's what you meant, it's worth adding a sentence about this right at the start, just to clarify this.

Comment: @user9303970, I'm not exactly sure what you mean with "the end of the line" (let alone going down one line). All it means is that the string that results when the variable is expanded isn't scanned for such special characters any more. That was done before the variable was expanded, and a `;` in a variable is just a plain character.

Comment: Exactly, I'm sure you understood me. Thanks.